# AWS S3 extremely slow, how to improve performance

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am experiencing extremely slow download speeds from AWS S3. I compared image download speed from AWSS3 vs Tesla site (from where I took the image).

I noticed that AWSS3 was approximately 10 times slower, why is this ?

Try to download the image in your browser and count the time until it is fully downloaded, from these two different url's, you would notice that AWS S3 is extremely slow.

AWS S3 Url: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hey-my-test-bucket/Red_Bay-1440.jpg

Tesla Url (where the image was taken from): https://www.tesla.com/tesla_theme/assets/img/models/v1.0/slideshow/Red_Bay-1440.jpg?20171006

Comment: The first time the browser loads the image in cache, the second time the image is loaded instantly.

Comment: For improving performance, you can use AWS CloudFront to speed up the performance of your static resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesla.com is using the Akamai CDN where S3 images are not.

https://www.cdnplanet.com/tools/cdnfinder/#site:https://www.tesla.com/tesla_theme/assets/img/models/v1.0/slideshow/Red_Bay-1440.jpg?20171006

As @EleazarEnrique suggests you could use AWS CloudFront which is basically a CDN or you can use some other CDN like CloudFlare.com or one of the many other CDN's.

Both CloudFront and CloudFlare have a "free" pricing plans also (with some limitations).